# PayPal integration for android crowdfunding app

Tags: android, paypal, donations

I am designing a crowdfunding android application. In this, users should be able to donate money to a cause they wish for. How can I create a page for this? The page should prompt the user for the amount he/she wants to donate. The app owner gets a certain cut from the donation. I am new to android, so please forgive me if I'm asking for too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to import PayPal sdk and make appropriate calls to it .More can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/android-integration-guide/).

Also, PayPal will approve/disapprove your request to activate and integrate their sdk on your app. So before going forward with above link, get your business model approved by them.

Don't loose heart if disapproved, there are many other gateways, if your app is good one and for a good cause.